# Daterange sorted by date and group by hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have a msql table that has data input ever hour of every day, so each date is entered 24 times and then a hour field as seen below...

How do I get the information between a daterange ?

Here is what I have, but I think the time is stopping it from working...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
```

Hee is the table I want to get information by the date...

unit ID   |       Date    |    Time    |   Power     |   Volts   |  Current   |

```
1         10/15/2010    21:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/15/2010    22:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/15/2010    23:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    00:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    01:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    02:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    03:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    04:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    05:00:00       245            220          100
1         10/16/2010    06:00:00       360            220          100
1         10/16/2010    07:00:00       596            220          100
1         10/16/2010    08:00:00      1567            220          100
1         10/16/2010    09:00:00      1568            220          100
1         10/16/2010    10:00:00      1598            220          100
1         10/16/2010    11:00:00      1642            220          100
1         10/16/2010    12:00:00      1658            220          100
1         10/16/2010    13:00:00      1664            220          100
1         10/16/2010    14:00:00      1598            220          100
1         10/16/2010    15:00:00      1527            220          100
1         10/16/2010    16:00:00       980            220          100
1         10/16/2010    17:00:00       410            220          100
1         10/16/2010    18:00:00       208            220          100
1         10/16/2010    19:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    20:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    21:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    22:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/16/2010    23:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/17/2010    00:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/17/2010    01:00:00         0            220          100
1         10/17/2010    02:00:00         0            220          100
```

The Date is `DATE`, the Time field is `TIME`, Power, Volt and Current are `FLOAT`.

The `$start` and `$end` are dates from a datepicker

```
    $start = (isset($_POST['start1'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['start1'])) : date("Y-m-d");

$end   = (isset($_POST['end1'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['end1'])) : date("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: what types do your Date and Time fields have? what values do conain $start and $end variables?

Comment: what is the type of date field ?

Comment: What's the query string look like? Are you checking for errors after running `mysql_query()`? Something like `$stmt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want *all* the points from all the dates, you can ignore you time column and your query will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single (') quotes from the variables $start and $end.

By using single quotes, you are making your variables a string.

Just use

$sql = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE date BETWEEN $start AND $end";

In your mysql table the date is in the format m-D-Y, whereas in your php code, its Y-m-d. The date format in ur php code should be similar to your mysql date format.